# Pasar la función cvMaxS de c++ a python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Encontré un código en C++ con OpenCV y no encuentro por ningún lado la función `cvMaxS` equivalente en Python, ¿alguien me podría decir como se programa esa linea en Python?

Entiendo que es extraer los pixeles con valor 150 del canal rojo, pero no encuentro esa función con OpenCV para Python.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

cv::Mat pixelMotion();
cv::Mat fireRGB(cv::Mat frame);

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture video("test_fire_2.mp4");
    cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2;
    pMOG2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

    if (!video.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Can not open video" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cv::Mat originalFrame;
    cv::Mat resultFrame;
    cv::namedWindow("OriginalVideo", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::namedWindow("ResultVideo", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;

    while (1) {
        video >> originalFrame;
        cv::medianBlur(originalFrame, resultFrame, 3);
        cv::split(resultFrame, channels);
        IplImage *redChannelImg;
        redChannelImg = &IplImage(channels[2]);
        cvMaxS(redChannelImg, 150, redChannelImg);
        cv::Mat temp = cv::cvarrToMat(redChannelImg);
        pMOG2->apply(temp, temp);
        channels.clear();
        cv::imshow("OriginalVideo", originalFrame);
        cv::imshow("ResultVideo", temp);

        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) {
                break;
        }
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    originalFrame.release();
    resultFrame.release();
    pMOG2.release();
    video.release();
    return 0;
}

cv::Mat pixelMotion(){
    return cv::Mat();
}

cv::Mat fireRGB(cv::Mat frame)
    return cv::Mat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La función existía en OpenCV 2.x, se llamaba `MaxS` ([cv2.MaxS](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mulspectrums#cv.MaxS)). No extae los pixeles con valor 150, lo que hace es calcular para cada elemento (canal rojo para el pixel) el valor máximo entre el valor del componente rojo y 150. Por ejemplo:

> ```
> rojo = [162, 140, 123, 200]
> cv2.MaxS(rojo, 150, rojo)
> rojo = [162, 150, 150, 200]
> ```

Actualmente puedes usar puedes [`numpy.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.maximum(red_channel, 150, red_channel)
```

Comment: otra pregunta el red_channel se optiene asi?  red_channel = frame.copy()
 red_channel[:, :, 0] = 0
 red_channel[:, :, 1] = 0    es que si compila pero no hace nada

Comment: No, eso hace que todos los valores del canal azul (o el que sea) sean 0. Opencv usa BGR no RGB por lo general si no has cambiado el colorspace. Debería ser `red_channel = frame[::2].copy()`

Comment: gracias! como veras estoy muy perdida pero es que apenas estoy aprendiendo